# How to convert a tensor into a list of tensors

Tags: python, list, pytorch, tensor

How can I convert a tensor into a list of tensors. For instance: `P1` is a `torch.Tensor` with *60* values in it and I want a list of tensors with *60* tensors in it.

Comment: Are you looking for a more elegant that doesn't have loop? Because you can just loop over and append them to an empty list.

Answer (score 6):

You can coerce the `torch.Tensor` to a *list* with `list`:

```
>>> P1 = torch.rand(60)
>>> list(P1)
[tensor(0.5987),
 tensor(0.5321),
 tensor(0.6590),
 ...
 tensor(0.1381)]
```

This works with multi-dimensional tensors too:

```
>>> P1 = torch.rand(60, 2)
>>> list(P1)
[tensor([0.4675, 0.0430]),
 tensor([0.2175, 0.6271]),
 tensor([0.3378, 0.8516]),
 ...,
 tensor([0.5099, 0.3411]
```